# setDisplayStats showing 'Shoddy' Font Images

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to Cocos2D and currently still learning. I have bene attempting to find the fix for this issue I am running into but just figuring out the search query on Google to get the answer has proved to be a daunting task.

Right off the bat, I am running into a problem when testing out the Hello World example (pretty much the vanilla template that gets generated when you create a new project in Xcode.

Note the bottom-left  corner in the image that should explain my entire problem:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9tKnM.jpg]

Also note that I am using Cocos2d 2.0 and Xcode 4.4 and this does not seem to happen in Cocos2d 1.0.1 but there is only DisplayFPS in that version (I think?)

After further testing this does not happen in Retina devices for the simulator - Only non-Retina devices i.e. iPad/iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that all of these images are in your project (usually under Resources group):

- fps-images.png
- fps-images-hd.png
- fps-images-ipadhd.png

If one of the files is missing, you'll see the distortion on certain devices depending on which files are missing.

The files may be missing if you started the project with an older template (v1.0.1 or earlier) that didn't include the -hd and -ipadhd images.

Comment: Great to hear back from you, Steffen! I will double check on this once I get home from the office. Just wanted to let you know that the reason I have been learning Cocos2D is to gain a solid foundation to get myself up and running with Kobold2D :) I know this wasn't recommended but your book has made available the resources to  easily go through Cocos2D as a stepping stone anyway - besides, doesn't hurt to learn both.

Thank you very much for providing us with such great resources to enter the complex world of iOS game dev!

Comment: Yes, I seem to have all 3 of those resources. Maybe I should try re-installing Cocos2D?

Comment: After a full re-install of cocos2d and re-adding the lib files to the project everything is working fine again! No idea what happened.